# Can I use Open Directory with a Leopard client and a Lion server?

Tags: opendirectory, osx-leopard, osx-lion

I've looked around on the interwebs but I can't find any sort of answer.
I just picked up a Mac Mini and I'm going to throw Lion Server on it for my network.

Most of my computers are running either Leopard or Snow Leopard (one iMac is a PowerPC so I can't upgrade to Lion).

I'd like to use Open Directory for all my network authentication but I want to make sure that the Lion Server can authenticate my iMac running Leopard.

Comment: I'm seeing close votes and not sure why. This is a server question directly relating to Open Directory network authentication.

Comment: From the [faq]: `"and it is not about: Networking outside the professional workplace"`

Comment: I'm deploying machines in a professional workplace. I'm setting up a tech network within our church to be able to deploy presentation computers across 4 campuses over a vpn.

Comment: I'm using Open Directory to manage authentication for over 40 volunteers within our organization.

Comment: Honestly, I read your opening statement as `"I just picked up a Mac Mini and I'm going to throw Lion Server on it for my **home** network."` One of those close votes was from me (and is my mistake). Not sure why the other is. I wouldn't worry though. If it gets closed, just flag it for re-opening. I doubt that it will actually be closed though. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested Lion server directly, but I've done variations of this with just about every other version of Mac OSX client and server and its been fine. I've had Lion clients connecting to an Open Directory domain with a mix of Snow Leopard and Leopard Servers just fine.

Open directory is based on a fairly mature set of principles and standards and - despite gui changes - hasn't changed that much at heart. I'm fairly sure it will be fine.

Comment: This appears to be correct. The only limitation is that you can't add the Leopard machine as a "Device" within the profile manager.